# Fast in-place replacement of some values in a numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

There has got to be a faster way to do in place replacement of values, right?  I've got a 2D array representing a grid of elevations/bathymetry.  I want to replace anything over 0 with NAN and this way is super slow:

```
for x in range(elevation.shape[0]):
    for y in range(elevation.shape[1]):
        if elevation[x,y] > 0:
            elevation[x,y] = numpy.NAN
```

It seems like that has so be a much better way!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
elevation[elevation > 0] = numpy.NAN
```

See [Indexing with Boolean Arrays](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268) in the NumPy tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

```
np.putmask(elevation, elevation > 0, np.nan)
```